# Why won't my video play any sound on Safari even though I didn't touch that configuration at all?

Tags: html, debugging, video, safari

I just don't understand how my video just doesn't want to play any sound on Safari mobile browser.  I've tried a laundry list of things I found on the web and on SO but to no avail.

What can I do to fix this?  Code's below.

```
<video width="100%" id="vid-player" class="vid img-responsive" style="max-width: 100%;" autoplay playsinline><source src="${this.fill}" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag</video>`
```

Answer (score 1):

In April of 2018, Google updated Chrome such that videos no longer autoplay without users' consent. Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: I got you, but even though I click the screen, audio still won't play :(